# how to destroy a detached shared memory immediately

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I created a shared memory with key 1234 using `shmget()` and terminated that process. next time when I run that same program, I want to create another shared memory with the same key 1234, But when I try so, it retrieves the old shared memory segment which is created by the already terminated process. So I tried `shmctl()` with `IPC_RMID` option and this system call returns success. But even after If I try to create a shared memory it gives me the old one. There is no other processes attached with this shared memory segment. That means `shm_nattch` value is zero at the time of removing shared memory segment.

How can I remove a shared segment immediately, and make the same old key usable to create a new non-existing shared memory segment?

Comment: I'll suggest that you post the code

Comment: Did you also detatch it from all processes using the shared memory with `shmdt()`?